# How to separate out display and data mxgraph ports example

Tags: mxgraph, jgraph

I am working with mxgraph and using the mxgraph ports example as a starting point for my application. https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/ports.html

The example passes the content of each cell through the `value` property of an `mxcell` object. The display content is an html label which is then rendered inside the cell. Example code below shows the creation of an draggable icon on the sidebar the parameters are `graph, sidebar, label, image`.

```
addSidebarIcon(graph, sidebar,
                '<h1 style="margin:0px;">Website</h1><br>'+
                '<img src="images/icons48/earth.png" width="48" height="48">'+
                '<br>'+
                '<a href="http://www.jgraph.com" target="_blank">Browse</a>',
                'images/icons48/earth.png');
```

The `addSideBarIcon` function then creates the vertex by passing it's `label` argument as the `value` property of the MxCell.

```
v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, label, x, y, 120, 120);
```

I would like to be able to add a JSON object to store non display data along with the html label for display purposes in the `value` property of each cell. I would like to do this without modifying the underlying prototypes.

```
addSidebarIcon(graph,
    sidebar, {
        display: '<h1 style="margin:0px;">Process</h1><br>' +
            '<img src="images/icons48/gear.png" width="48" height="48">' +
            '<br><select><option>Value1</option><option>Value2</option></select><br>',
        data: {
            key1: val1
        },
    }
```

When I do this he code is interpreting the `value` as an html label. where as I would like it to interpret only `value.display` as the label. I'm not sure how to go about combining the html label and json data together and would love some suggestions.

[image: Blank Blank image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the implementation of the addSidebarIcon in the same file...

When you find the:

```
v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, label, x, y, 120, 120);
```

You have to use there not the "label", but extract the display value from your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the implementation of `mxGraph.getLabel`, which is called by mxGraph to display label.

```js
graph.getLabel = function(cell) {
    // extract label from cell.value
    // and return a DOM node for html or string for plain text
    return createDOMNode(cell.value.display);
}
```

See also: [mxGraph.getLabel](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.getLabel)